# Asyncio with ProcessPoolExecutor shutdown before finishing all tasks

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, process-pool

I wanted to combine ProcessPoolExecutor with asyncio to run my blocking functions in TestClass concurrently. Each task is intended to be run long-time, so i need a working shutdown process to make things smooth after exiting my script. Any ideas where do i need to add error handling for KeyboardInterrupt to smoothly shutdown all tasks and processes? I have searched a lot of topics related and none of them solves my issue to work as i wanted. Hope to get some help! Thanks in advance.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = 2


async def task(loop,executor_processes, i):
    print(f"[TASK {i}] Initializing Abck class")
    new_test = await loop.run_in_executor(executor_processes,TestClass)
    # other async and sync functions contained in TestClass
    print(f"[TASK {i}] Finished")


async def main():
    executor_processes = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

    loop_ = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = []

    for i in range(1, 100):
        tasks.append(task(loop_, executor_processes, i))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("ctrl + c")
    finally:
        print('Program finished')
```

Here are error logs after pressing ctrl + c before all tasks and processes are finished.

```
Fatal Python error: Fatal Python error: init_import_sizeinit_import_size: : Failed to import the site moduleFailed to import the site module

Python runtime state: Python runtime state: initializedinitialized

Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 580, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 580, in <module>
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 580, in <module>
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 580, in <module>
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 563, in main
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 563, in main
    main()
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 563, in main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 563, in main
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 495, in venv
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 495, in venv
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 495, in venv
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 495, in venv
    addsitepackages(known_paths, [sys.prefix])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 350, in addsitepackages
    addsitepackages(known_paths, [sys.prefix])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 350, in addsitepackages
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 563, in main
    addsitepackages(known_paths, [sys.prefix])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 350, in addsitepackages
    addsitepackages(known_paths, [sys.prefix])
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 350, in addsitepackages
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 495, in venv
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
    exec(line)
    exec(line)
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
    from . import abc
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/abc.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    addsitepackages(known_paths, [sys.prefix])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 350, in addsitepackages
    from contextlib import contextmanager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 165, in <module>
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 14, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 5, in <module>
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 160, in addpackage
    f = io.TextIOWrapper(io.open_code(fullname))
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 580, in _compile_bytecode
KeyboardInterrupt
    from . import machinery
KeyboardInterrupt
    from functools import wraps
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 438, in <module>
    from collections import deque
    class _AsyncGeneratorContextManager(_GeneratorContextManagerBase,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 85, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
KeyboardInterrupt
    from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
    _CacheInfo = namedtuple("CacheInfo", ["hits", "misses", "maxsize", "currsize"])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 394, in namedtuple
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 580, in _compile_bytecode
Exception in thread QueueManagerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    exec(s, namespace)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ctrl + c
Program finished
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 394, in _queue_management_worker
    work_item.future.set_exception(bpe)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 539, in set_exception
    raise InvalidStateError('{}: {!r}'.format(self._state, self))
concurrent.futures._base.InvalidStateError: CANCELLED: <Future at 0x7ffed1f2f250 state=cancelled>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Windows Solution**

If you are running on Windows  then CTRL-C interrupt handling does not seem to work too well with multiprocessing pools. The following is a bit clumsy but seems to work after a fashion.

The idea is to initialize each process in the multiprocessing pool with a global variable `ctrl_c_entered` that is set initially to `False`. I have completed your class `TestClass` with a method `foo` which will be the worker function invoked. It must when invoked:

1. Test the global flag `ctrl_c_entered` and if True, immediately return.
2. Have its own KeyboardInterrupt handler and on such an interrupt it must set the global `ctrl_c_entered` flag to True and return.
3. **Update**: However, the CTRL-C could be entered when the pool process has not transferred control to the worker function. For instance, it could be in the process of grabbing from the input queue the next task to run. In this case there would otherwise be no `try/catch` for KeyboardInterrupt exceptions in effect. So we needs to set an interrupt handler for the SIGINT interrupt for each process in the pool that will set the `ctrl_c_entered` flag to `True`. But this now means that the *original*, default `SIGINT` interrupt handler must be temporarily restored in Step 2 above in order to catch KeyboardInterrupt exceptions.

You also have to let all the submitted asyncio tasks complete. So we set a `signal.SIGINT` interrupt handler that sets a global `ctrl_c_entered` flags for the main process to `True` if CTRL-C has been entered (we do *not* break out of the `asyncio.run(main()` statement. Our long-running asyncio tasks must check this `ctrl_c_entered` flag and terminate if it is set to True.

```py
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import signal
import time
from functools import wraps

def handle_ctrl_c(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global ctrl_c_entered
        if not ctrl_c_entered:
            signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, default_sigint_handler) # the default
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                ctrl_c_entered = True
                return KeyboardInterrupt()
            finally:
                signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, pool_ctrl_c_handler)
        else:
            return KeyboardInterrupt()
    return wrapper


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = 2

    @handle_ctrl_c
    def foo(self, i):
        time.sleep(1)
        return i ** 2

async def task(loop, executor_processes, i):
    # If this is a long-running task, periodically check running flag and return if set.
    # For example:
    if ctrl_c_entered:
        return KeyboardInterrupt()
    print(f"[TASK {i}] Initializing Abck class")
    new_test = await loop.run_in_executor(executor_processes, TestClass().foo, i)
    # other async and sync functions contained in TestClass
    print(f"[TASK {i}] Finished")
    return new_test

def pool_ctrl_c_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    global ctrl_c_entered
    ctrl_c_entered = True

def init_pool():
    # set global variable for each process in the pool:
    global ctrl_c_entered
    global default_sigint_handler
    ctrl_c_entered = False
    default_sigint_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, pool_ctrl_c_handler)

async def main():
    executor_processes = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5, initializer=init_pool)

    loop_ = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = []

    for i in range(1, 100):
        tasks.append(task(loop_, executor_processes, i))

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(results)

def ctrl_c_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    global ctrl_c_entered
    ctrl_c_entered = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctrl_c_entered = False
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c_handler)
    asyncio.run(main())
    print('Program finished')
```

Prints:

```
[TASK 1] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 2] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 3] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 4] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 5] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 6] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 7] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 8] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 9] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 10] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 11] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 12] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 13] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 14] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 15] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 16] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 17] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 18] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 19] Initializing Abck class
[TASK 1] Finished
[TASK 2] Finished
[TASK 3] Finished
[TASK 4] Finished
[TASK 5] Finished
[TASK 6] Finished
[TASK 7] Finished
[TASK 9] Finished
[TASK 8] Finished
[TASK 10] Finished
ctrl + c
ctrl + c
ctrl + c
ctrl + c
ctrl + c
[TASK 13] Finished
[TASK 16] Finished
[TASK 17] Finished
[TASK 18] Finished
[TASK 19] Finished
[TASK 14] Finished
[TASK 12] Finished
[TASK 11] Finished
[TASK 15] Finished
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt(), KeyboardInterrupt()]
```

**Linux and Platforms that Use Fork Solution**

This is simpler in that interrupt handling more or less works for multiprocessing pools. The easiest way to handle this is to again have a global `running` flag initialized for each pool process that the worker function can periodically check and terminate if `False`. Each pool process will set a CTRL-C handler and set `running` to False when the user has entered CTRL-C. This will take care of terminating any already-running tasks. The main process can simply handle the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception:

```py
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import signal
import time

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = 2

    def foo(self):
        for _ in range(20):
            if not running:
                return
            time.sleep(.1)

async def task(loop, executor_processes, i):
    print(f"[TASK {i}] Initializing Abck class")
    new_test = await loop.run_in_executor(executor_processes, TestClass().foo)
    # other async and sync functions contained in TestClass
    print(f"[TASK {i}] Finished")

def ctrl_c_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    global running
    running = False

def init_pool():
    global running
    running = True
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c_handler)

async def main():
    executor_processes = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5, initializer=init_pool)

    loop_ = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = []

    for i in range(1, 100):
        tasks.append(task(loop_, executor_processes, i))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("ctrl + c")
print('Program finished')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also have tried this example but with `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` and `done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks,return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)`
instead of `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` and using global variable. It seems to have similar effects. What I found interesting is that if you call ctrl+c before TestClass has been initialized in all tasks it also raises this error.

Comment: Actually, I just updated the Windows Solution. See the new Step 3 description. There is a window when the Ctrl-C could be entered when a pool process in not actually running a task but is perhaps just about to. That could cause an unhandled exception. See the updated solution.

Comment: I tried your updated code and it raises another error `concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.` while trying to stop the script in that scenario from Step 3 in your reply.

Comment: The updated code was supposed to avoid something like that. It's not happening when I run it. What version of Python are you running?

Comment: 3.8.5, tried on macos and windows, same issue

Comment: I am running 3.8.5 on Windows 10 and cannot duplicate this problem. This happens every time you run this? For MacOs you should use the "Linux and Platforms that Use Fork Solution".

Comment: I modified the Windows version of `foo` to take an argument and to return a result (it squares its argument) and to have `main` print out the 20 results (reduced from 100 to keep the listing reasonably sized). If a Ctrl-C occurs then the result returned is an instance of `KeyboardException`. I entered Ctrl-C after the first 10 of 20 tasks completed.

Comment: Yes, it happens every time from what i have observerd. What version of futures package do you have?

Comment: My bad, i now realised you are entering ctrl+c after `Initializing Abck class` is done on all tasks, I get this error when i try to stop the code during doing that. For example:       
`[TASK 1] Initializing Abck class`  
`[TASK 2] Initializing Abck class`  
`[TASK 3] Initializing Abck class`
`[TASK 4] Initializing Abck class`
`[TASK 5] Initializing Abck class`
`[TASK 6] Initializing Abck class`
`[TASK 7] Initializing Abck class`
`[TASK 8] Initializing Abck class`
`[TASK 9] Initializing Abck class`
`ctrl + c`
`errors here`

Comment: When I enter ctrl + c in the moment you did, everything works fine

Comment: You're not at fault; I did not test that possibility and you have to be *very* fast to even be able to do that  -- but that doesn't seem to be too serious. I will take a look at this.

Comment: Try running 1000 tasks, it is easier to hit that error then, just press ctrl+c after you started the script

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't think I immediately have a solution for that. I have again updated the Windows source however. I have created a decorator function, `handle_ctrl_c` that you can decorate your pool worker function with. All the interrupt handling is in this decorator, I have switched the global `running` flag to be the more intuitive `ctrl_c_entered` flag, which is initially `False`.

Comment: And one more change to the Windows source: a missing global statement function in function `pool_ctrl_c_entered`. I don't immediately notice this because there is only a small window in which this function would ever get executed and the side-effect of the statement being missing is that we might end up executing an extra task even after Ctrl-C had been entered because the global flag had not been set. I apologize, anyway.

Comment: No worries at all, i have actually spotted that before.

Comment: I managed to catch that BrokenProcessPool error using `with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5, initializer=init_pool) as executor_processes` and then `try/catch`. However i still got many `KeyboardInterrupt` errors, most of them starts with `<frozen importlib...`, do you have any idea if this is catchable as well?

Comment: If the try/except is surrounding the entire `with` block, then on the exception you will be exiting the `with` block and there is an implicit call to `terminate` on the pool killing all the running processes, which is the opposite of what the rest of the code is trying to accomplish. But I tried all sorts of different ways and I can't suppress output messages and the exception I catch is **A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.** or **The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request**